# Ionic Capacitor: Open SQLite file using file chooser

Tags: android, sqlite, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-native

I'm working on an Ionic Capacitor app and would like to implement the following feature:

1. user presses a button
2. a file chooser opens
3. user can select an SQLite database file
4. the app accesses the file and can work with the database

I already managed to implement steps 1-3 using

- https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/chooser
- https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/file-chooser/
- ion-input HTML tag with type="file" attribute

But when I try to open the selected file using Ionic's native SQLite plugin (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite) I get stuck, no matter which file chooser I used in the previous step.

Does anybody have an idea, how I can fix this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: `I get stuck` -> What do you mean by that? You have to specify your problem. With the following two plugins I got exactly this functionality implemented: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@capacitor-community/sqlite and https://www.npmjs.com/package/@robingenz/capacitor-file-picker

Comment: @RGe Can you please share the code of your implementation? I do not understand how to feed the data from the file chooser into the SQLite plugin.

Comment: No, as it is proprietary software from a client (protected).

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://npmjs.com/package/@capacitor-community/sqlite for the database.

Something like this:

```js
import { CapacitorSQLite, SQLiteConnection } from '@capacitor-community/sqlite';
import { FilePicker } from '@robingenz/capacitor-file-picker';

async function main() {
  const result = await FilePicker.pickFiles();
  const file = result.files[0];

  const sqlite = new SQLiteConnection(CapacitorSQLite);
  const db = await sqlite.createNCConnection(file.path, 1);
  await db.open();

  // You can now read/write to the database using the db object
}
```